# need help to update record of database in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-update

I am developing a plugin now i want to update my table record.... I'm using this code to fetch data from database

```
  <?php
    $id = $_GET\['id'\];
    $dirname = dirname(__FILE__);
    $root = false !== mb_strpos( $dirname, 'wp-content' ) ? mb_substr( $dirname, 0, mb_strpos( $dirname, 'wp-content' ) ) : $dirname;
    require_once( $root . "wp-load.php" );

        global $wpdb;
         $post_name_table = $wpdb->prefix . "tropix_dmin";
         $query = "
            SELECT post_name1, id
            FROM $post_name_table
            WHERE id= $id";
        $post_name1_results = $wpdb->get_results($query);   
    ?>    
      <table class="widefat" style="border-radius:4px;">
      <tr>
        <th class="manage-column" scope="col" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px;">Field</th>
        <th class="manage-column" scope="col" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px;">Value</th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach ( $post_name1_results as $post_names ) {        
        $this_data = unserialize($post_names->post_name1);
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($this_data);      
        if($this_data != ""){    
       ?>
      <tr class="alternate iedit">
        <td class="column-columnname">Street Address</td>
        <td class="column-columnname"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $this_data\['$Street_Address'\]; ?>"  /></td>
      </tr>
 <?php }
  } ?>
    </table>
```

But i need to update data... also i am sending the screenshot of the database.... please help me

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kset.jpg
```

Comment: where you want to update?

Comment: Hello vel thankx for comment.... i want to update Street address with this <input type="text" value="<?php echo $this_data\['$Street_Address'\]; ?>"  />

Comment: when you wan to update?

Comment: I am inserting data in the database and the other page i just want to show those current value which is saved already through echo and the wee will go for update data

Answer (score -1):

if you want to update a column your query should be:

```
   $query = "UPDATE (*table*) SET (*column to update*) = '*value*' WHERE id= $id";
```

to echo an existing column, use:

```
$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$query = mysqli_query($this->db_connection,"SELECT *column* FROM *table* WHERE id='*your id*'");
$value = mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $value[0]['column name'];
```

Care with SQL Injection though.

Comment: Thank you luuktap but with this, the data in the input box is not showing

Comment: Wait, do you want to echo the value of a column to <td class="column-columnname">Street Address</td> ?

Comment: Yes first i want to echo the current value which is already in the database and then update the value with update query

Comment: @aliarslan Updated the answer :)

Comment: I think you can do it with `wheile...` too, but this works for me.

Comment: i have 300+ value which i want so update so this is not gone well for that